# Smooth container resizing in svelte

Tags: svelte

I've been using svelte for a while and it's great but there is one thing I run into over and over again. Let's take the following code:

```html
<script>
    import {flip} from 'svelte/animate';
    import {fade} from 'svelte/transition';
    
    let list = [];
</script>

<div class="this-div-should-smoothly-change-size">
    {#each list as item (item)}
        <div animate:flip transition:fade>
            {item}
            <button on:click={() => (list = list.filter(e => e !== item))}>X</button>
        </div>
    {/each} 
</div>

<button on:click={() => (list = [...list, Math.random()])}>
    Add
</button>
```

The flip animations on the list look great but the button below it still "jumps". All I want is to make the button move smoothly. Is it possible in svelte to make a container smoothly transition between sizes when its content changes?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the limitation of svelte compiler,
`"An element that uses the animate directive must be the immediate child of a keyed each block"`, we cannot simply add `animate:flip` to button.

But you can work around it if you're ok to change your html structure a bit.

```html
<script>
import { flip } from 'svelte/animate'
import { fade } from 'svelte/transition'

const buttonPlaceholder = Symbol('buttonPlaceholder')
let list = []
</script>

<div class="this-div-should-smoothly-change-size">
  {#each list.concat(buttonPlaceholder) as item (item)}
    <div animate:flip transition:fade>
      {#if item == buttonPlaceholder}
        <button on:click={() => (list = [...list, Math.random()])}> Add </button>
      {:else}
        {item}
        <button on:click={() => (list = list.filter(e => e !== item))}>X</button>
      {/if}
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I used to do but it doesn't work in a context where instead of a button there is just the rest of the page.

Comment: It's possible to achieve, by using custom action and directly call internal `create_animation` API. I put together a sloppy [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/8abe6e061b6c405f97f2ac6c226eac12?version=3.35.0) to illustrate the idea. It's not perfect, but show you the idea.

Comment: Idea is to use a "spy" that coordinate the button with each block items. To refine this impl, we need to provide a custom `flip` function which returns a `tick` function then use it as the spy. Ref: [source](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/internal/animations.ts),